# Generate oauth2orize access token programmatically for test user?

Tags: ifttt, oauth2orize

How can I generate a usable (live, authenticated) access token without forcing the client through redirect/authentication?

I'm building an IFTTT channel with node/express/oauth2orize. IFTTT requires that a test user can be generated by the endpoint `test/setup`. I need to return an access token that can be used for the subsequent tests.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the Authentication Tests first, then copy the access token in one of the responses. Then use that value in your test/setup response.